# Charging a card stored in vault not working for paypal sandbox mode

Tags: php, cakephp, paypal, cakephp-2.0

I am integrating paypal in my project. I am storing card in paypal vault. It is working fine.
But charging a stored card in totally not working.
Here is what i tried.

The url i am hitting
`https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment`

The headers i sent
`Content-Type : application/json`
`Authorization : Bearer A101.cckgmkChgGI1jLstRxxxxxxxx`

and the body

```
{
  "intent":"sale",
      "payer": {
           "payment_method":"credit_card",
           "funding_instruments":[
              {
                  "credit_card_token":{
                       "credit_card_id":"CARD-62T3953xxxxx",
                       "payer_id":"user12345"
                   }
               }
           ]
       },
"transactions":[
    {
        "amount":{
            "total":"125",
            "currency":"USD"
         },
         "description":"This is test payment"
   }
 ]
}
```

and the response i am getting

```
{
  "name": "INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",
  "information_link": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",
  "debug_id": "aa518e23593df"
}
```

and the information link given is not working

Comment: Nobody knows the answer, I'm still waiting :(

Answer (score 0):

You should use credit card info in sandbox accounts that created in PayPal App to store to vault. Then it will work with creating payment. Good luck!